# QComboBox become ugly when changing main windows background

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qstylesheet

Before changing:

[image]

After changing parent widget `styleSheet` property to this:

```
background-color: rgb(5, 34, 78);
```

I see this:

[image]

`QComboBox` become really different. What happens? How to use regular QComboBox on dark background?

I am using Qt 5.5 without QML.

Comment: Setting stylesheet discards style. Try using [QPalette](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qpalette.html).

Comment: @Amartel thanks, that work. Can you provide expanded description of happened problem so I will accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set it to the main window only

`yourWindow->setStyleSheet("{background-color: #HexNumber}");`

or tell the QComboBox to not have style:
`yourWindow->setStyleSheet("QComboBox{background-color:none}");`

or

`yourWindow->setStyleSheet("QComboBox#ComboName{background-color:none}");`

Answer (score 1):

According to [manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/stylesheet.html):

> When a style sheet is active, the QStyle returned by QWidget::style()
>   is a wrapper "style sheet" style, not the platform-specific style. The
>   wrapper style ensures that any active style sheet is respected and
>   otherwise forwards the drawing operations to the underlying,
>   platform-specific style (e.g., QWindowsXPStyle on Windows XP).

If all you want is to change some colors, leaving selected style unchanged, the better solution would be to use [QPalette](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qpalette.html).